# Magento 2 : Unable to View Customer's Listing Page in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, customer

I am unable to view customers grid in admin. When I clicking on `Customers ==> All Customers` I get an error 500. Need help, which module might be corrupt or missing.

Thanks

Comment: Please check `var\log` or `var\report` folder for error